# Boost library write_json put extra new line at the end

Tags: json, boost

I am learning from http://www.cochoy.fr/boost-property-tree/.
Instead of write_json to stdout, I tried to save it in a string.

```
std::stringstream  ss;
boost::property_tree::json_parser::write_json(ss, oroot, false);
std::cout <<" begin json string" << std::endl;
std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
std::cout << "after json string" << std::endl;
```

output:

```
 begin json string
{"height":"320","some":{"complex":{"path":"bonjour"}},"animals":{"rabbit":"white","dog":"brown","cat":"grey"},"fish":"blue","fish":"yellow","fruits":["apple","raspberry","orange"],"matrix":[["1","2","3"],["4","5","6"],["7","8","9"]]}

after json string
```

According to the output above, there is a new empty line at the end. How to get rid of the new line? Because with the new line it is not a valid JSON string.

Comment: The trailing newline doesn't in fact make it invalid JSON. However, your receiving end may object to there being trailing data, not part of the top-level JSON object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newline is not explicitly mentioned in the [JSON RFC-7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159) but it is defined as part of the [POSIX standard for a line](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_206).

Incase you're interested in where the newline comes from you can take a look at the [write_json_internal source code](https://github.com/boostorg/property_tree/blob/develop/include/boost/property_tree/json_parser/detail/write.hpp), we can see that there is an `stream << std::endl;` near the end of the method. Note that **...::write_json** references **write_json_internal**.

```
 // Write ptree to json stream
template<class Ptree>
void write_json_internal(std::basic_ostream<typename Ptree::key_type::value_type> &stream, 
                         const Ptree &pt,
                         const std::string &filename,
                         bool pretty)
{
    if (!verify_json(pt, 0))
        BOOST_PROPERTY_TREE_THROW(json_parser_error("ptree contains data that cannot be represented in JSON format", filename, 0));
    write_json_helper(stream, pt, 0, pretty);
    stream << std::endl;
    if (!stream.good())
        BOOST_PROPERTY_TREE_THROW(json_parser_error("write error", filename, 0));
}
```

Comment: "Ceterum censeo abusus PropertyTreeum viruperandum esse." IOW. [Don't use Property Tree as if it were a JSON library](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a85371%20property_tree%20json). The line end is really the least of your worries. See https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/json/doc/html/index.html

Comment: Ow. Late typo spot. "vituperandum".